# Gradle Sync issues - Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4-all.zip'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting the following error:

[image]

How can I reset the Gradle system to use? I imagine there is some kind of issue with the version and just resetting or redownloading Gradle may fix this.

UPDATE 1: Trying using `https`, as suggested by @CommonsWare.

[image]

UPDATE 2: Throwing some errors about "invalid content":

[image]

UPDATE 3: Now I'm getting this error but it looks like it is not a Gradle build issue anymore, but something I need to examine and fix in my code:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried switching to `https`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am trying that. It seems to be downloading something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Now I'm getting errors about "invalid content". See my UPDATE 2 in the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare It looks like Gradle is working now. See my updates. So the problem was using `http` where `https` was needed. Please write it as an answer so that I mark it as question answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may have dropped `http` support for their server somewhere along the line. I have been using `https` for those URLs for quite some time without a problem.